# How do I access second level JSON values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use JSON data from a HTTPS request to fill parameters based on the request however I keep coming across the same error:

```
>                  index.js:45
>                  value: request.body.header.value
>                                             ^
>  
>  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

I seem to have no trouble with accessing the first layer items, however I cannot work around the above error for anything past the first level.
Here is what my script looks like so far:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { PKPass } = require("passkit-generator");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
var fs = require("file-system");
var path = require("path");
var axios = require("axios");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var storageRef = admin.storage().bucket()

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var bigint = parseInt(hex, 16);
    var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
    var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
    var b = bigint & 255;

    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}

exports.pass = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    PKPass.from({
        model: "./model/BoardingPass.pass",
        certificates: {
            wwdr: fs.fs.readFileSync("./certs/wwdr.pem"),
            signerCert: fs.fs.readFileSync("./certs/passIdentifierSignerCert.pem"),
            signerKey: fs.fs.readFileSync("./certs/passIdentifierSignerKey.pem"),
            signerKeyPassphrase: "PASSPHRASE"
        },
    },
    {
        authenticationToken: "AUTHTOKEN",
        webServiceURL: "WEBSERVICEURL",
        serialNumber: request.body.serialNumber,
        description: request.body.description,
        logoText: request.body.logoText,
        foregroundColor: hexToRgb("#" + request.body.foregroundColour),
        backgroundColor: hexToRgb("#" + request.body.backgroundColour)

    })
    .then(async (newPass) => {
        newPass.headerFields.push(
            {
                key: "gate",
                label: "GATE",
                value: request.body.header.value
            }
        )
        newPass.primaryFields.push(
            {
                key: "depart",
                label: request.body.primary[0].label,
                value: request.body.primary[0].value
            },
            {
                key: "arrive",
                label: request.body.primary[1].label,
                value: request.body.primary[1].value
            }
        )
        newPass.secondaryFields.push(
            {
                key: "passenger",
                label: "PASSENGER",
                value: request.body.secondary.value
            }
        )
        newPass.auxiliaryFields.push(
            {
                key: "boardingTime",
                label: "DEPART",
                value: request.body.auxiliary[0].value
            },
            {
                key: "flightNewName",
                label: "FLIGHT",
                value: request.body.auxiliary[1].value
            },
            {
                key: "class",
                label: "CLASS",
                value: request.body.auxiliary[2].value
            },
            {
                key: "date",
                label: "DATE",
                value: request.body.auxiliary[3].value
            }
        )
        newPass.backFields.push(
            {
                key: "passport",
                label: "PASSPORT",
                value: request.bodyback[0].value
            },
            {
                key: "residence",
                label: "RESIDENCE",
                value: request.body.back[1].value
            }
        )

        newPass.setBarcodes({
            message: request.body.barcode,
            format: "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
            messageEncoding: "iso-8859-1"
        })

        const resp = await axios.get(request.body.thumbnail, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
        const buffer = Buffer.from(resp.data, "utf-8")
        newPass.addBuffer("thumbnail.png", buffer)
        newPass.addBuffer("thumbnail@2x.png", buffer)
        const bufferData = newPass.getAsBuffer();
        fs.writeFileSync("new.pkpass", bufferData)
        storageRef.file("passes/boardingPass.pkpass")
            .save(bufferData, (error) => {
                if (!error) {
                    console.log("Pass was uploaded successfully.");
                    response.status(200);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("There was an error uploading pass");
                    response.status(400);
                }
            })
    })
});
```

And this is the HTTPS POST request:

```
{
    "barcode": "TESTBARCODE",
    "thumbnail": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png",
    "serialNumber": "TESTSERIAL",
    "description": "TESTDESCRIPTION",
    "logoText": "TESTLOGOTEXT",
    "foregroundColour": "#FFFFFF",
    "backgroundColour": "#000000",
    "header": [{
        "value": "21"
    }],
    "primary": [
        {
            "label": "Melbourne",
            "value": "MEL"
        },
        {
            "label": "Singapore",
            "value": "SNG"
        }
    ],
    "secondary": {
        "value": "TEST PASSENGER NAME"
    },
    "auxiliary": [
        {
            "value": "11:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "value": "999"
        },
        {
            "value": "Economy"
        },
        {
            "value": "1/12"
        }
    ],
    "back": [
        {
            "value": "COUNTRY"
        },
        {
            "value": "1 Flinders Street, Melbourne, Victoria, 3000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Regardless of what is after `response.body.*.<HERE>` the same error occurs.

Comment: You have to access **every** level; you can't just **skip the array** that is the value of `header` and treat the object instead that array as the array itself.

Answer (score 2):

`request.body.header` looks like an array, not an object>

```
    "header": [{
        "value": "21"
    }],
```

So maybe you need to index into the array to find `value`:

```
request.body.header[0].value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried with `request.body.header[0].value` but am still getting the same error. I believe it is something to do with the source code and not the necessarily request as this error happens for .primary[0] too.

Comment: You definitely won't get the **exact** same error if you use my suggestion.  If you are seeing the **exact** same error, then you didn't actually change the code.  If you are getting a different error, then you should probably post a new question describing the new problem.

Comment: This is the error I get with `value: request.body.header[0].value`: 
```>                  value: request.body.header[0].value
>                                            ^
>  
>  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')```